# multiplication of two columns in dataframe SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, dataframe

I`ve a large dataframe, Im trying to do a simple multipication between two columns and put the results in new column when I do that I'm getting this error message :

SettingWithCopyWarning : a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a dataframe.

my code looks like this :

```
DF[‘mult‘]=DF[‘price‘]*DF[‘rate‘]
```

I Tried loc but didnt work .. does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) answer your question?

Comment: What you're doing is right, please add some extra code to reproduce the warning.

Comment: it's possible that he/she already have a column named 'mult'

Answer (score 0):

You should use [df.assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) in this case:

`df2 = DF.assign(mult=DF[‘price‘]*DF[‘rate‘])`

You get back a new dataframe with a 'mult' column added.